# The other div moves along with the first div (on the animation of the first div)

Tags: html, css, animation, webkit-animation

My aim is to build a image slider, where WHILE the APPLE logo animation runs, the apple products swoop by from under. The problem is this, I have added @keyframes animation to make the iPhone appear from right (our right) and then leave as it swoops put of the screen to left.

But then when I added the MACBOOK, and I didn't even add an animation to it or anything, it runs along with the iPhone!

Here's the html and styles:

**html:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Slider</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/styles_Apple.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/styles_Google.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/styles_Samsung.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/styles_Nikon.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="slider">
            <div class="Apple_logo"><img src="images/logos/Apple_logo color.png" style="width:100px; height:125px;"></div>
            <div class="iPhone_6"><img src="images/mobiles/Mobile1.png" style="height:400px" width="200px;"</div>
            <div class="Apple_Macbook"><img src="images/laptops/apple macbook pro 2.png" style="height:400px; width:550px;"></div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**styles:**

```
.slider
{
    height:600px;
    width:980px;
    border:thick;
    border-color:#000;
    border-style:groove;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.Apple_logo
{
    border:thick;
    border-color:#000;
    border-style:groove;
    width:100px;
    margin-left:1000px;
    -webkit-animation-name:Apple_logo_appear;
    -webkit-animation-duration:10s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes Apple_logo_appear
{
    0%{margin-left:1000px; opacity:.3}
    50%{margin-left:440px; opacity:1}
    100%{margin-left:440px; opacity:0;}
}

.iPhone_6
{
    position:absolute;
    border:thick;
    border-color:#000;
    border-style:groove;
    width:200px;
    height:400px;
    margin-left:1000px;
    -webkit-animation-name:iPhone_6_appear;
    -webkit-animation-duration:2s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes iPhone_6_appear
{
    0%{margin-left:1000px; opacity:.3}
    50%{margin-left:440px; opacity:1}
    100%{margin-left:-500px; opacity:0;}
}

.Apple_Macbook
{
    border:thick;
    border-color:#000;
    border-style:groove;
    margin-left:1300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code isn't right:

```
<div class="iPhone_6"><img src="images/mobiles/Mobile1.png" style="height:400px" width="200px;"</div>
```

it should be

```
<div class="iPhone_6"><img src="images/mobiles/Mobile1.png" style="height:400px;width:200px;"></div>
```

(notation of the height/width parameters within the style attribute, and the `<img>` tag isn't closed - this should be the cause of your problem.)